# CURL авторизация с прокси

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Пытаюсь зайти при помощи прокси с логином и паролем. Страница просто бесконечно грузится. Пробовал гуляться с разными параметрами, безуспешно. Прокси 100% валидный:

```
public function requestJSON( $url, $postArray = null, $options = null )
{

    if( is_array( $postArray ) )
        // $postArray = http_build_query( $postArray );
        $postArray = json_encode( $postArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );

    $this->curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->curlCookieSavePath );
    curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->curlCookieSavePath );

    curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ( 
                                                    'Accept: application/vnd.qiwi.sso-v1+json',
                                                    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                                                    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
                                                )
    );
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '8000');
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '1.2.3.4.5');
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'login:psw');


    if( $postArray ) 
    {

        curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArray );

    }

    if( is_array( $options ) && count( $options ) )
    {

        curl_setopt_array( $this->curl, $options );

    }


    $response = curl_exec( $this->curl );

    curl_close( $this->curl );

    return $response;

}
```

Comment: А как именно должна происходить аутентификация на прокси? Ведь есть разные методы - CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH с CURLAUTH_BASIC, CURLAUTH_DIGEST, CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE, CURLAUTH_NTLM, CURLAUTH_ANY, y CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE.

Comment: Можете показать, что имеете ввиду?

Comment: Ну так вас спрашивают как авторизация на прокси происходит? каким методом?